# Weird failure in PHP if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

OK, so here's my code. (I'll sanitize it later. Don't worry about it.)

`gallery_upload_new.php`

```
// Check if user wants to upload to existing or new album
if (isset($_POST['album'])) {
    if ($_POST['album'] == '') {
        $_POST['album'] = $_POST['new_album'];
    }
}

// Populate album dropdown menu
$albums = $database->query("SELECT DISTINCT(album) FROM images")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); 

// Load the 'upload new photo' interface if user's not uploading it already
if (!isset($_FILES['image_link']) || !isset($_POST['caption']) || $_POST['caption'] == '') {
    //var_dump($_FILES);
    //var_dump($_POST);
    include('views/gallery_upload_new.php');

// Otherwise store the image file, register it into database, and put the user back in the list of photos
} else {
    $new_image = new Image($_POST['caption'], $_POST['album']);
    $new_image->register($_FILES['image_link']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image_link']['name']);
    header('location: gallery_management.php'); 
}
?>
```

`views/gallery_upload_new.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $site_title; ?></title>
        <?php include('views/header.php'); //Just the global CSS and JavaScript ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('views/nav_menu.php'); //Site navigation panel ?>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Upload new photo</h1>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="gallery_upload_new.php" method="post">
                <p>
                    <strong>Upload to album: </strong>
                    <select name="album">
                        <?php
foreach($albums as $album_name) {
    echo "<option value='$album_name'>$album_name</option>";
}
                        ?>
                        <option id="selectNewAlbum" value="" selected>New album</option> <input type="text" placeholder="New album name" name="new_album" id="newAlbumName">
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p><strong>Photo caption</strong> <input type="text" name="caption"></p>
                <p><strong>Photo file: </strong><input type="file" required name="image_link"></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Unggah">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the weird part: without those two `var_dump`'s up there, the `else` block won't execute. I've made sure the indexes in the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are correct. Yet without those dummy dumps, this thing won't work. It'd just load the `views/gallery_upload_new.php` no matter what.

It doesn't even matter if they're commented out or not. They just need to be there.

What did I do wrong? Did I made a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: Could it be something inside the include that screws things up? If you remove it and place a dummy instruction, does the else execute normally?

Comment: Yeah. If you are not uploading a file image_link, or the POST index caption is not empty (string) you include the gallery_upload_new file. So it's either the redirect or the included file which doesn't work.

Comment: I've included the `view` script. The other `include`s are used in other similar scripts with no trouble, so I reckon they aren't the troublemaker.

Comment: @starleaf1 do a `print_r($_FILES)` and `print_r($_POST)` just before the `if` statement and post the output please so we can replicate

Comment: @AlexAndrei The `else` block executes properly when I do so. This is getting weirder.

Comment: @starleaf1 give me the contents of the `POST` and `FILES` arrays

Comment: The problem seems to have magically disappeared. I think I'll have to write this off as a bug on PHP's part.